# java mybatis isTraceEnabled()Z error

Tags: java, logging, log4j, mybatis

While printing mybatis SQL statements on console I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger.isTraceEnabled()Z
```

I use log4j which is supported by mybatis.

My log4j.properties file:

```
### Global logging configuration
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

log4j.logger.com.app.mybatis.dao=stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] - %m%n
```

Strange thing is that if I specify a class to be logged, for example

```
log4j.logger.com.app.mybatis.dao.MyClass=stdout
```

it works fine but not for the package. Any idea of what would be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade the log4j to the version **1.2.12+**

The method `org.apache.log4j.Logger.isTraceEnabled()`, including `org.apache.log4j.Level.TRACE` was added since version 1.2.12

---

<sub>* Currently, the latest version is 1.2.17</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using

> org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory.useCustomLogging

method and giving a parameter as a custom logging class that extends Log4jImpl class. I overrode isTraceEnabled method. So error giving method would not be called anymore.